# stored procedure column value determined by value of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table of data something like this.

```
date, amount, price
2009-10-12, 20, 15.43
2009-10-13, -10, 6.98
```

I need to write a stored procedure that will return these column as well as create a new column that indicates whether the amount was positive or negative.  So the end result of the procedure would look something like this.

```
date, amount, price, result
2009-10-12, 20, 15.43, positive
2009-10-13, -10, 6.98, negative
```

How can this be done?  This is a sql 2008 ent db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select  date, 
        amount, 
        price, 
        case when amount > 0 then 'positive' 
             when amount < 0 then 'negative' 
        end as positive_or_negative
from #table
```

Comment: yep, that will do the job.  Thanks guys